# Section name with UTF-8 characters using CJK package with beamer

Tags: beamer, cjk

I am using PdfLatex to generate some slides, but I have some troubles using the CJK package to include UTF-8 characters.

The source code is attached below. When generating the pdf file, I get an error saying `! Missing \endcsname inserted.`. If I comment out line 12, it works. If I change the package on line 3 to `\usepackage{CJKutf8}`, it also works. Why is this happening?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{CJK}    % line 3

\begin{document}
\CJK{UTF8}{gbsn}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{一}
\end{frame}

\section{三}         % line 12

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{二}
\end{frame}

\endCJK
\end{document}
```

Comment: I switched to XeLaTeX instead and avoided this problem.